# How can i fix my Ground detection code?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, algorithm, sfml

My ground detection works by checking if the player's x position is between the range of a sprite xpos+16 and xpos-16 if it is,then it uses a separate axis theorem  on the y axis to see if the player is colliding or touching with the sprite if it is then the player is grounded. Else then the player isn't grounded.
[image]

```
void groundCheck(Player& player,sf::Sprite sprite)
{

        sf::Vector2f bounds = sf::Vector2f((sprite.getPosition().x - 16),(sprite.getPosition().x + 16));

  //if(player.grounded == false)
  if(player.sprite.getPosition().x < bounds.y && player.sprite.getPosition().x > bounds.x )
    {
        float lengthy = abs(player.sprite.getPosition().y-sprite.getPosition().y);
        float half1y = player.sprite.getGlobalBounds().height/2;
        float half2y = sprite.getGlobalBounds().height/2;
        float gapy = lengthy - half1y - half2y;
        if(gapy <= 0)
        {
            player.grounded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            player.grounded = false;
            std::cout << gapy <<","<<half2y<<","<<half1y<<","<<lengthy<<","<<player.sprite.getPosition().y<<"\n"; //<<","
        }
    }


}
```

The problem is that when there are 2 or more sprites with the same x position ,the check then performs sat on all sprites below the player and I'm not sure what a solution to this would be.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple sprites at the same position, are they all supposed to prevent the player from falling? if so, you can either merge them, or disable collision for one.

Else, if not all the sprites should collide, maybe you can add a flag to indicate if they are ground colliders.

On a side note, you could use a complete AABB instead of using arbitrary values to detect if the player is y-aligned.